# Caching a Template in php

Tags: php, caching

I have a template which is of .php extension.
This template contains the html maarkup along with some php variables. This is how it looks like.

```
include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/header.php';

include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/content/'.$this->view.'.php';

include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/leftsidebar.php';

include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/rightsidebar.php';
```

This is the way i am caching.

```
ob_start();
include_once('template.php');
$templateCache = ob_get_clean();
```

Then i store this in a .cache file.

The problem is when i load the template from cache, it is not able to read the php variables.

I know i am doing something wrong but not able to catch it. Please help.

Comment: And for what purpose are you using this cache? You are substituting variable with values, and writing it to cache so on next run you don't have to assemble it one more time. It 's how the cache works...

Comment: @dev-null-dweller - Thanks. I am having a little confusion here. I want to separate the static content from the variables. So that i can cache the static content. I know i cannot achieve this with the way i am doing this. Is their any other option i can opt ? I dont need any code, but just little idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Caching in general

Caching, by definition, caches the values of the respective variables.

What you want to do is to delete the cache when one of the variables used in the template changes its value.

This way, the cache will get regenerated, with the new values, and you'll have the advantages of both worlds:

- on one side, a speedier HTTP answer, when there's a cache hit
- on the other side, dynamicity of the page, when some values change

## Caching in your case

Disclaimer: *This does not necessarily uses your problem as a showcase. You should improve your question if you need a more to-the-point answer*.

If your template has some areas that change often, and some that don't, then you should cache separately only those portions that do not change often, and leave the overall template which contains the changing variables uncached as a whole.

Do not forget to treat individual caches as described above to have a proper behavior of the system.

So instead of caching the whole file, you rewrite it as something like this:

```
echo $cache->get(VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/header.php');//<-- this is a cache
include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/content/'.$this->view.'.php');
echo $cache->get(VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/leftsidebar.php');//<-- this is a cache
echo $cache->get(VIEWDIR . 'documentation/common/rightsidebar.php');//<-- this is a cache
```

and you treat the individual parts of the template as caches themselves.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But is their any way of caching the static content leaving the variables. I am little confused and not able to pose my question properly. My template is always constant except few variables. I dont want the static template to load again and again when i refresh.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Then you should cache separately only those portions that do not change often, and leave the overall template which contains the changing variables uncached as a whole.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand your answer. Will reply back soon.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha Sure, just ask if something is not clear, so I can improve my answer so that you and other readers can benefit from it as well.

Comment: Thanks. I got what you are saying. Makes sense. The only thing i didnt understand is how do i cache specific parts of my template ? This is exactly what i want. I know my template structure is not correct. How about this. Lets say i the second include will vary always(see my code). So what i do is i write a comment above and below of that line. So when i load the cache, i do a preg_replace and change the content inside. What do you think ?

Comment: @AbhishekSaha see my edit. Does it make sense now? What you previously attempted to cache, you break up in parts instead: those which can be cached, and those which can't, and you cache only those which make sense to be cached.

Comment: Beautiful...I like your answer. Very clear, neat and easy to understand. Thanks a ton. You made my day.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not cache them.
Your way of "caching" is not caching at all, but it is not the main problem.
The thing is that I doubt you have any reason to cache your templates or their output.

So, just leave everything as is, without any "caching".

Comment: Thanks. As you see in my templete.php, the header and the sidebars are always constant. So i dont want to load them again and again. The only thing which varies is the second include. include_once VIEWDIR . 'documentation/content/'.$this->view.'.php'; Is their any other approach to this ?

Comment: Is this a good way: If i make the template with .html extension, then ofcourse the php variables will not be parsed. And then when i include this cache, i change the header content-type as php, so that it can parse the php variables. Will this work ?